# How do you set up Haskell + ghc-mod on OS/X?

Tags: haskell

I first set up Haskell from https://www.haskell.org/platform/ but ghc-mod had problems with sandboxes and to update it I needed a newer cabal which needed a newer ghc. Or something like that. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28049104/131227 ??)

So I deleted everything, and installed from http://ghcformacosx.github.io/.
Then some strange failure setting up a new sandbox was because something didn't properly have a dependancy for happy. (https://github.com/haskell-suite/haskell-src-exts/issues/14)

Ok. Installed happy. Now trying (again) to install ghc-mod and I get a giant mess (below).

Should I use http://www.stackage.org/?
I've seen some people mention `ghc-pkg recache` or `cabal install cabal-install`... Are those things I need to do?

Mess:

```
Resolving dependencies... Configuring ghc-mod-5.2.1.2... Building ghc-mod-5.2.1.2... Failed to install ghc-mod-5.2.1.2 Build log ( /Users/mark/.cabal/logs/ghc-mod-5.2.1.2.log ): Configuring ghc-mod-5.2.1.2... Building ghc-mod-5.2.1.2... Preprocessing library ghc-mod-5.2.1.2...

Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Convert.hs:1:51: Warning:
    -XOverlappingInstances is deprecated: instead use per-instance pragmas OVERLAPPING/OVERLAPPABLE/OVERLAPS [ 1 of 38] Compiling Language.Haskell.GhcMod.Read ( Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Read.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Read.o ) [ 2 of 38] Compiling Language.Haskell.GhcMod.Cabal21 ( Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Cabal21.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Cabal21.o ) [ 3 of 38] Compiling Language.Haskell.GhcMod.Cabal18 ( Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Cabal18.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Cabal18.o ) [ 4 of 38] Compiling Language.Haskell.GhcMod.Cabal16 ( Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Cabal16.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Cabal16.o ) [ 5 of 38] Compiling Language.Haskell.GhcMod.GHCChoice ( Language/Haskell/GhcMod/GHCChoice.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/GhcMod/GHCChoice.o ) [ 6 of 38] Compiling Language.Haskell.GhcMod.Error ( Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Error.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Error.o )

Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Error.hs:12:1: Warning:
    Module ‘Control.Monad.Error’ is deprecated:
      Use Control.Monad.Except instead

Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Error.hs:40:10: Warning:
    In the use of type constructor or class ‘Error’
    (imported from Control.Monad.Error, but defined in Control.Monad.Trans.Error):
    Deprecated: "Use Control.Monad.Trans.Except instead"

Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Error.hs:40:10: Warning:
    In the use of type constructor or class ‘Error’
    (imported from Control.Monad.Error, but defined in Control.Monad.Trans.Error):
    Deprecated: "Use Control.Monad.Trans.Except instead" [ 7 of 38] Compiling Language.Haskell.GhcMod.Utils ( Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Utils.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Utils.o )

Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Utils.hs:15:1: Warning:
    The import of ‘Control.Applicative’ is redundant
      except perhaps to import instances from ‘Control.Applicative’
    To import instances alone, use: import Control.Applicative()

Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Utils.hs:45:51: Warning:
    In the use of ‘strMsg’
    (imported from Language.Haskell.GhcMod.Error, but defined in Control.Monad.Trans.Error):
    Deprecated: "Use Control.Monad.Trans.Except instead" [ 8 of 38] Compiling Language.Haskell.GhcMod.Types ( Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Types.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Types.o ) [ 9 of 38] Compiling Language.Haskell.GhcMod.Gap ( Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Gap.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Gap.o )

Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Gap.hs:256:18:
    Not in scope: data constructor ‘ExposePackageId’
    Perhaps you meant ‘ExposePackage’ (imported from DynFlags) cabal: Error: some packages failed to install: ghc-mod-5.2.1.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was: ExitFailure 1
```

After applying the accepted answer (which seemed to install ghc-mod), running gch-mod gives the following:

```
> ghc-mod check x.hs
cabal-helper-wrapper: Installing a private copy of Cabal, this might take a
while but will only happen once per Cabal version.

If anything goes horribly wrong just delete this directory and try again:
    /Users/mark/.ghc-mod/cabal-helper

If you want to avoid this automatic installation altogether install version
1.22.0.0 of Cabal manually (into your user or global package-db):
    $ cabal install Cabal-1.22.0.0
...In order, the following would be installed:
filepath-1.3.0.1 (latest: 1.4.0.0) (new version)
directory-1.2.2.1 (new version)
process-1.2.3.0 (reinstall) changes: directory-1.2.2.0 -> 1.2.2.1,
filepath-1.4.0.0 -> 1.3.0.1
Cabal-1.22.0.0 (latest: 1.22.2.0) (new version)
cabal: The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:
ghc-7.10.1
Cabal-1.22.2.0
Use --force-reinstalls if you want to install anyway.
cabal-helper-wrapper: Installing Cabal version 1.22.0.0 failed.
nYou have two choices now:
- Either you install this version of Cabal in your globa/luser package-db
  somehow
n- Or you can see if you can update your cabal-install to use a different
  version of the Cabal library that we can build with:
    $ cabal install cabal-install --constraint 'Cabal > 1.22.0.0'
nTo check the version cabal-install is currently using try:
    $ cabal --version

ghc-mod: readCreateProcess: /Users/mark/.cabal/libexec/cabal-helper-wrapper "/Users/mark/work/haskell/ixberg/dist" "entrypoints" "source-dirs" "ghc-options" "ghc-src-options" "ghc-pkg-options" "--with-ghc=ghc" "--with-ghc-pkg=ghc-pkg" "--with-cabal=cabal" (exit 1): failed
```

Strangely, it wants the version of Cabal that is currently installed:

```
> cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.22.0.0
using version 1.22.0.0 of the Cabal library
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Edit (August 2015) Better fix

A better command line tool for installing Haskell binaries and libraries by the awesome [FPComplete](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/06/stack-0-1-release) group called [stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack) means you can install ghc-mod with `stack install ghc-mod` (outside a project to make it global) and it will just work. The binary will be installed to `~/.local/bin` and should be put on your path so your editor can find it.

I will leave the below for anyone who wishes to know what cabal Hell really meant.

### Problem With DanielG's Fork

I asked on the Haskell reddit and NihillstDandy explained that the GHC for Mac OS X does not register the Cabal library. This is not true for your install from http://ghcformacosx.github.io/. It does register the Cabal library.

ghc-mod needs the cabal library to work, but it does not compile with the cabal library. Instead it compiles with cabal-helper and that looks to see if you have a registered version of the cabal library. If it does not find any then `cabal-helper-wrapper` will install a private copy and in this case it tired to install the same version as what cabal-install was compiled with, cabal-1.22.0.0.

When I installed DanielG's Fork it worked for my current project, but after testing it in other projects I am getting the same error you are. This is a problem with the fork and not Haskell (as far as I can tell).

---

### Original Answer

So, while I was putting this post together ghc-mod was fixed for GHC-7.10. Thanks to DanielG!

- `git clone https://github.com/DanielG/ghc-mod`
- `cd ghc-mod`
- `cabal install -j4`

And if you get errors that say "setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.2.0-x86_64-osx-ghc-7.10.1: The program 'happy' version
>=1.17 is required but it could not be found."

- `cabal install happy -j4`

The same for any other problems and it should work. (Although you have happy installed, so it should just work).

---

The rest of the post is on how to downgrade the cabal executable, also known as cabal-install, to version 1.20.0.3. Although you could really use this to downgrade to any version. Since there is a working fork of ghc-mod that works with GHC-7.10 and cabal-1.22 you do not need to downgrade to fix ghc-mod.

I'm just leaving the rest of the post up here since, unfortunately, this is a problem with Haskell as a whole. [Halcyon](https://halcyon.sh/) and [nix](http://www.pavelkogan.com/2014/07/09/haskell-development-with-nix/) are ways to deal with Haskell's shortcomings in this regard.

---

### How to downgrade Cabal in Haskell

When I wrote this post ghc-mod, nor any fork, compiled with GHC-7.10 and versions below 7.10 broke with cabal-1.22 sandboxes.

However, even if you compile ghc-mod with GHC-7.8.4 (the version before 7.10) and cabal-1.20.0.3 you still cannot use ghc-mod inside a sandbox created by cabal-1.22 and above. So the only way to use ghc-mod is to either downgrade your entire system to cabal-1.20.0.3 or don't use sandboxes. This means you can still use GHC-7.10, but you have to use the older version of cabal. That is unless you want to wait until the convener or someone else fixes it for GHC-7.10. Its been over a week already, but some kind Haskell programmer fixed it in a fork (see above).

---

If this is something you still want here is how to compile ghc-mod with GHC-7.8.4 and cabal-1.20.0.3. Also, I replace the executable cabal-1.22 with the older cabal-1.20.0.3. Note, it does not matter what directory you download the sources to.

- download GHC-7.8.4 source for your OS from [here](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_8_4)
- `tar -xf path_to_zipped_source`
- `cd path_to_ghc-7.8.4`

The next steps will install ghc-7.8.4 as ghc-7.8.4 in the same folder as ghc-7.10 is install for you. The -j4 is to tell make to use 4 threads to compile it.

- `./configure`
- `make install -j4`

To get the correct version of cabal we can just ask cabal to get it.

- `cabal get cabal-install-1.20.0.3`
- `cd cabal-install-1.20.0.3`

Now to install cabal with ghc-7.8.4. Here cabal-1.22 will pull all the decencies and should give you some warning about installing another version of the cabal library (not to be confused with cabal-install), this should not cause problems.

- `cabal --with-compiler=ghc-7.8.4 install`

So now you should have cabal-1.20.0.4 installed, but not on your path. It will be in ~/.cabal/bin. We need to make this global, so remove cabal-1.22 (it only removes the symlink).

- rm `which cabal`

And create the symlink to cabal-1.20.0.4. Btw, you will need to remove any sandboxes you made with cabal-1.22 and remake them with cabal-1.20.0.4.

If you do not have `realpath` you can just type in the full path of cabal. I use it for connivence.

- `cd ~/.cabal/bin`
- ln -s `realpath cabal` /usr/local/bin

Now this is how I compiled ghc-mod on my mac (you may run into your own problems). I'm not sure why cabal couldn't do it in one call, but this worked in the end.

- `cabal --with-compiler=ghc-7.8.4 install happy`
- `cabal --with-compiler=ghc-7.8.4 install haskell-src-exts-1.16.0.1`
- `cabal --with-compiler=ghc-7.8.4 install hlint-1.9.19`
- `cabal --with-compiler=ghc-7.8.4 install ghc-mod`

Now you should be able to call ghc-mod from anywhere. To test it just type `ghc-mod` after you have `cabal sandbox init`. If it does not throw any errors then your in the clear.

Comment: Running ghc-mod after all of that yields `cabal-helper-wrapper: Installing a private copy of Cabal, this might take a
while but will only happen once per Cabal version. ... (exit 1): failed`

Comment: @z5h: Wait, did you clone DanielG's repo and install it or downgrade to cabal-1.20.0.3? Regardless, please update your post with more details of what you did to get the error. When running `ghc-mod` with no args you should get "ghc-mod: No command given (try --help)"

Comment: I cloned DanielG's repo. My OP has been updated with output. Thanks.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that I was trying to install yesod on top of ghcformacosx.github -- I got the 'happy' and 'alex' error's which I googled to bring me here. A simple `cabal install happy` `cabal install alex` worked!

Comment: Recommendation: use stack, not cabal. Especially for yesod! You might also want to look at the FPComplete editor or emacs plugin that makes life much easier for yesod.

Comment: stack installed gch-mod perfect, all OK. But there is a problem after deleting .stack folder: "ghc-mod: Could not find $libexecdir/cabal-helper-wrapper", by reason of "~/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-6.4/7.10.3/libexec". I've tried to change $libexecdir , not successfully.

Answer (score 2):

The version of executable `cabal` that is used to configure this project should be the same as the version of the global `Cabal` package.

It's easier to install a compatible version of `cabal-install` than `Cabal` as follows:

```
$ ghc-pkg list | grep Cabal
    Cabal-1.22.2.0
$ cabal install cabal-install-1.22.2.0
```

Or build one in sandbox and replace/shadow the original one.

Then don't forget to re-configure the project with the new `cabal`:

```
$ cabal clean && cabal configure
```

Now the `ghc-mod` should works.

Answer (score 0):

If Cabal-1.22 isn't registered (`ghc-pkg list cabal`), the `cabal-helper-wrapper` will install a private copy because it needs the library installed to work, but it doesn't want to stomp on anything you have that might break by upgrading `Cabal` directly.

GHC for Mac OS X doesn't register the `Cabal` library, it comes bundled with a version of `cabal-install` built against it.